# How to commit a MQ transaction in a camel route?

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq, mq, jbossfuse

There is a [camel](http://camel.apache.org/) route, which is transacted and exceptions are handled by a `TransactionErrorHandler`. The code looks something like this:

```
...
<bean
    id="errorHandler"
    class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder">
</bean>
...
<camelContext errorHandlerRef="errorHandler">
    ...
    <onException>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
        <!-- do some exception handling -->
    </onException>

    <route>
        <from uri="mq:queue://QMgr/Q?exchangePattern=InOut" />
        <transacted />
        <!-- some routing that throws an Exception -->
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

It works and there is a commit for the transaction after the error has been handled: `Transaction commit (0xfab75a3a) redelivered(true) for ...`, but then the message is placed in the input queue again and the transaction starts from the beginning (endless loop).

We are using [IBM MQ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq) and I think this rollback is performed by MQ and not from the camel route. So the question is: Can I tell MQ that I handled the exception and that it should not rollback again?

Comment: Can you share the full bean setup including transaction manager and connection factory? The wiring to the transaction manger isn't shown. Also, are you sure your route should be InOut? That setting would only apply if the incoming messages have a JMSReplyTo header.

Answer (score 1):

IBM MQ is resending the message to the consumer by design. To have the broker stop after X number of tries, configure a 'backout threshold' and a 'blackout queue' for IBM MQ to move the messages out of the way after failed delivery attempts.